# WSO2 ESB: the statistic feature is disable in cluster mode

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing, esb

It's just as the title said, the statistic feature is not working when I deploy ESB in cluster mode, although it runs well if I only use 1 ESB (normal mode).

What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is using WSO2 BAM. I have not found any other way when the cluster mode is enabled.